# Computing gradient and hessian of a function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f$ be a map from $R^n$ to $R$ so that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x \cdot (Ax) - x^T v + \alpha $ where $A$ is an $n by n$ symmetric and positive definite matrix. $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha $ is a scalar. IS there an easier way to compute the gradient and hessian of $f$?

It seems not too complicated but we still have a ltot of equations involved. Any ideas?

Comment: If you just set $n=2$ and work it out, you'll see what it has to be for a general $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) page of matrix calculus is helpful for such stuff.

Note that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

$$f(x)=\frac12 x^TAx-x^Tv+\alpha$$

$$\nabla f(x)=\frac12 (2Ax)-v=Ax-v$$

If we differentiate by $x$ again, $v$ as a constant vector will vanish and the first part is just linear combination of $x_i$.

$$\nabla^2 f(x)=A.$$

Compare the result with lower dimensions to make sure they agree.

Comment: I dont see how youre using that A is symmetric positive definite. Are you writing it as diagonal matrix?

Comment: I did not use the property of positive definite at all. However, I use the property that it is a symmetric matrix, suppose not, then the differentiating $x^TAx$ gives us $(A+A^T)x$.